# Why can checkboxes have top/bottom margins?

Tags: html, css, dom

Why does this style work:

```
input[type=checkbox] { margin-top: 50px; }
```

but not this:

```
span { margin-top: 50px; }
```

Both elements are `display: inline;`, and as far as I'm able to gather, neither `inline` nor `inline-block` elements are supposed to be able to have vertical margins.  Yet checkboxes seem to defy this rule...

Comment: They are `inline-block` rather than `inline`, and moreover at least Chrome won't even let you change it to `display: inline`,

Comment: @ExplosionPills: It turns out that Firebug erroneously reports them as `inline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they're `inline-block` elements just like `<textarea>` or `<button>` .. you certainly can apply everything to an inline-block element that you can a block-level element.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Firebug is reporting that the element is definitely `inline`.  I wonder if this is a bug in Firebug then.  Thank you for the info on `inline-block`.

Answer (score 2):

`inline-block` elements actually can have vertical margins.